# RegEx which starts with a letter and contains x characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a regular expression pattern in JavaScript which searches for strings which starts with a letter (e.g. letter B) and consists of fixed number of characters (e.g. 8)?

I have tried a lot of variations with `^B` followed by `[A-Za-z]{7}`, but nothing worked out.

**UPDATE:**

As a final solution an alternative version of [@stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev)'s answer worked for me. As I was filtering object attributes in a relational DB style, I had to match the exact string without returning records with multiple words starting with the matching string and separated by whitespaces.

The RegEx `\bB/S{7}$\b` worked, as a record can contain special characters, and the whitespace character acts as the word separator, as in any human-friendly table.

Comment: Your regex should work. Show the complete code and the expected input and output. You might need a modifier or two depending on your cases...

Comment: `^B. {7}/igm` this works

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Thank you very much. `^B.{7}` works with only the multiline flag, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\bB\w{7}\b` is a pattern for any word starting with `B` and that has 8 characters. Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/tF3aA5/1.

The word boundary `\b` enables the whole word matching.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Boundaries are something that is easy to overlook, but, in many cases, they are the culprits.